# No way to get the network address at the application layer? really? (omnet++)

Tags: networking, simulation, omnet++, simulator, inet

How can I check if the current node is the intended destination for these packets (has the same network address (IP addr) as in its wlan[0] (only) interface)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packet will be passed to the application layer of a node if and only if the destination IP address matches the IP address of this node.  Therefore, one may be sure that a packet received in an application layer has the same address as IP address of one of its interface.
However, if you still need the IP address of the node feel free to use one of methods from [L3AddressResolver](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/networklayer/common/L3AddressResolver.h), for example `addressOf()`:

```
cModule * host = getContainingNode(this);
L3Address addr = L3AddressResolver().addressOf(host);
```

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it earlier by calling get object by name ...